# MIDI output on a Mac?

Tags: osx, audio, midi

I am looking for software that simply can open a MIDI file on a Mac and send it to an external MIDI device (like a MIDI keyboard).

I understand Logic supports this, but is there something cheaper (or free) that would support this basic functionality without having to invest hundreds of dollars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to leverage MidiPipe to accomplish this.

http://www.subtlesoft.square7.net/MidiPipe.html